# Does trip insurance cover hurricanes?

Tags: insurance, natural-disasters

I am scheduled to leave Orlando FL and there is currently a hurricane coming in this general direction.

Does trip insurance cover me if the hurricane causes the flight to be cancelled.

This was a points award flight as well if that matters.

Comment: Depends on the insurance you buy.

Comment: Did you read your insurance contract? How do we know what it covers and what not?

Comment: Normally if the flight is cancelled the airline will reschedule your flight, so there may be no need for an insurance claim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to read your policy to know for sure.

There is some information [here](http://www.travelinsurancereview.net/faqs/does-travel-insurance-cover-natural-disasters/) about how trip insurance policies *usually* handle natural disasters.  In particular, it is relevant whether or not the disaster already existed at the time you bought the insurance.  For hurricanes, they suggest the relevant date is when the storm is named; for Irma that appears to have been August 30, so if you bought the insurance after that date, you might not be covered.

Again, it is entirely possible that your particular policy has different terms.  **You have to read it.**